# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Url Rewritng

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I have Action called Contact in home controller

```
<mysite>/Home/Contact
```

I want to be able by typing `<mysite>/Contact` to get the same result as `<mysite>/Home/Contact`

Is it possible to do with mvc 3.0 routes or RouteMagic?

Currently i am trying to achieve this like that, but no luck:

Custom Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Contact", // Route name
                "Contact", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

RouteMagic:

```
 var route = routes.MapRoute("new", "Contact");
            routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("old", "Home/Contact"))
              .To(route);
```

Update

Ok the custom routes should be defined first, now it is working(in case of custom routes), but there is appeared a new question `why route magic returning error`:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: controllerName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your new route occurs before the default route (since it will match as well) when defining the route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Contact", // Route name
    "contact", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: @Joper - the default route should be the last route added so that any specific routes get matched first.

Comment: may be you have any idea why RouteMagic in that case returning error 'Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: controllerName'

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the rewrite module in iis7 ?

its easy to use , donwlod it from here:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: i saw that, but better to use default advantage of MVC routes.